# How to populate a database from the client-side in Heroku

Tags: python, database, heroku

The application I'm developing implies that the user can populate a whole database by importing a csv file with the rows of a certain table. This operation might take several seconds and I run into the 30sec timeout problem.

I've seen an interesting solution in Flask that uses the python function "yield" https://librenepal.com/article/flask-and-heroku-timeout/ that I cannot reproduce without using Flask. I basically did the same and I return the following:

```
return HttpResponse(generateResponse(), content_type="text/html")
```

where genereateReponse is:

```
def generateResponse():
  for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(10)
    print(i)
    yield(i)
```

This approach tries to keep the connection alive, but as I've said it doesn't work.

I've also tried to send POST requests from the frontend to the server in Javascript to read a file that states the current status of the operation (pretty much like a sort of progressbar) thus creating a separate communication frontend -> backend and viceversa, but it does not seem to keep the increase the timeout window as expected.

I have also read about performing background operations in Heroku but it's probably not the way I should do it.

What would you recommend me to do? or how can I make the 30sec timeout longer?